# What's the relation between ACPI, udev, HAL and pm-utils

Tags: linux, udev, power-management, acpi, pm-utils

I'm trying to figure out how the power management in achieved in Linux because I want to fix some issues in my laptop. I have found thoughtful documentation about these elements separately. In other manuals, more problem-and-how-to-fix oriented, these elements are mentioned often. However, I could not find an overview that explains the relationship, and potential overlaps, of these concepts. I would need to have a general idea before going into more detail for each element separately.

Could someone give an overview to these concepts and their interactions?

Answer (score 1):

HAL is defunct and no longer used in modern distros.  ACPI is a specification for how the bios and kernel interact relating to system hardware enumeration and power management.  udev is a daemon that is notified by the kernel when hardware changes, such as when you plug in a new disk drive, and may take actions such as detecting what filesystems are on the disk, or noticing that it is part of a raid array and activating that array.  pm-utils is a set of command line utilities for doing things like suspend and hibernate the system.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was a bit also about their relationships. For example, I read somewhere that pm-utils is basically a set of high-level scripts that basically use HAL in the backstage. But if HAL is deprecated, how is this possible? And related, is pm-utils the only way to suspend a computer? Is this what Gnome uses to suspend the computer? Or does Gnome use other stuff, like HAL or udev...